# How to convert absolute path to relative path in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'd like to convert a path to a relative path in a PowerShell script.
How do I do this using PowerShell?

For example:

```
Path to convert: c:\documents\mynicefiles\afile.txt
Reference path:  c:\documents
Result:          mynicefiles\afile.txt
```

And

```
Path to convert: c:\documents\myproject1\afile.txt
Reference path:  c:\documents\myproject2
Result:          ..\myproject1\afile.txt
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I found something built in, [Resolve-Path](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849858.aspx):

```
Resolve-Path -Relative
```

This returns the path relative to the current location. A simple usage:

```
$root = "C:\Users\Dave\"
$current = "C:\Users\Dave\Documents\"
$tmp = Get-Location
Set-Location $root
Resolve-Path -relative $current
Set-Location $tmp
```

Comment: Rather than using a temporary variable, you can also use Push-Location and Pop-Location to set the location and then revert back to its original value. Same basic solution but without the temporary variable.

Comment: This will fail if the root directory doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Clever, but I don't like the side effect of changing your working directory (even though you switch it back)

Comment: To make sure current location will be restored even when `Resolve-Path` throws an exception (depending on `$ErrorActionPreference`), wrap code in try/catch: `try{ push-location $root; resolve-path -relative $current } finally{ pop-location }`

Comment: They finally added a `-RelativeBasePath` parameter in Powershell 7.4.0 so you don't need to use `Set-Location` anymore: `Resolve-Path -Relative $current -RelativeBasePath $root`

Comment: Maybe add an answer to that effect @zett42

Comment: @DaveHillier Done: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77656498/7571258

Answer (score 18):

Using the built-in [System.IO.Path.GetRelativePath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getrelativepath) is simpler than the accepted answer:

```
[System.IO.Path]::GetRelativePath($relativeTo, $path)
```

Comment: I'd disagree with the "safer" though it is simpler. Note: this only works in .Net 5.0 RC and .Net core

Comment: In Windows 10, it requires a separate download and install of Powershell Core in order to support this .Net Core method. The accepted answer works out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12396272/438570), but it changes your current directory (it reverts back), but if you really need to isolate that process, code example below can help. It does the same thing, just in a new PowerShell instance.

```
function Get-RelativePath($path, $relativeTo) {
    $powershell = (Get-Process -PID $PID | Get-Item)
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($powershell)) {
        $powershell = "powershell.exe"
    }

    & $powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& { Set-Location `"$relativeTo`"; Resolve-Path `"$path`" -Relative}"
}
```

It's really slow though, you should really use the other version unless you absolutely have to use this.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I have multiple "roots" from which I want to generate relative file paths. I have found `Resolve-Path -Relative` unusable in this kind of situation. Changing a global setting, current location, in order to generate a relative file path seems error-prone and (if you're writing parallel code) possibly not thread-safe.

The following should work in early or recent versions of Powershell and Powershell Core, doesn't change your current directory, even temporarily, and is OS-independent and thread-safe.

It doesn't address the second example from OP (inserting `..` as required.)

```
function Get-RelativePath {
    param($path, $relativeTo)
    # strip trailing slash
    $relativeTo = Join-Path `
                      (Split-Path -Parent $relativeTo) `
                      (Split-Path -Leaf $relativeTo)
    $relPath = Split-Path -Leaf $path
    $path = Split-Path -Parent $path
    do {    
        $leaf = Split-Path -Leaf $path
        $relPath = Join-Path $leaf $relPath
        $path = Split-Path -Parent $path
    } until (($path -eq $relativeTo) -Or ($path.Length -eq 0))
    $relPath
}
```

An example:

```
PS> $configRoot = 'C:\Users\P799634t\code\RMP\v2\AWD'
PS> $queryPath = 'C:\Users\P799634t\code\RMP\v2\AWD\config_queries\LOAD_UNQ_QUEUE_QUERY2.sql'
PS> Write-Host (Get-RelativePath $queryPath $configRoot)
config_queries\LOAD_UNQ_QUEUE_QUERY2.sql
```

It behaves reasonably when one file path is not a sub-path of the other:

```
PS> $root = 'C:\Users\P799634t\code\RMP\v2\AWD'
PS> $notRelated = 'E:\path\to\origami'
PS> Write-Host (Get-RelativePath $notRelated $root)
E:\path\to\origami
```

Answer (score 1):

Since **Powershell 7.4.0** you can use new `Resolve-Path` parameter [`-RelativeBasePath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/resolve-path?view=powershell-7.4#-relativebasepath) to do this in one line. The `Set-Location` workaround has finally become obsolete:

```bash
$pathToConvert = 'c:\documents\mynicefiles\afile.txt'
$referencePath = 'c:\documents'

Resolve-Path -Relative -Path $pathToConvert -RelativeBasePath $referencePath
```

**Output:**

```
.\mynicefiles\afile.txt
```

**NOTE:**

The arguments for `-Path` and `-RelativeBasePath` must both be **existing** paths! There is another restriction, which appears to be a [bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20918) in the current implementation though - the arguments must be *filesystem* paths.

The advantage of the [.NET method `System.IO.Path.GetRelativePath`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64540612/7571258) is that it works with non-existing paths as well.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy way would be :

```
$current -replace [regex]::Escape($root), '.'
```

Or if you want the relative path from your actual current location

```
$path -replace [regex]::Escape((pwd).Path), '.'
```

This assumes all your paths are valid.

Comment: This doesn't work if $root is not a root of $current (see example 2 of Question)

Answer (score -4):

Here is an alternative approach

```
$pathToConvert1 = "c:\documents\mynicefiles\afile.txt"
$referencePath1 = "c:\documents"
$result1 = $pathToConvert1.Substring($referencePath1.Length + 1)
#$result1:  mynicefiles\afile.txt
```

And

```
$pathToConvert2 = "c:\documents\myproject1\afile.txt"
#$referencePath2 = "c:\documents\myproject2"
$result2 = "..\myproject" + [regex]::Replace($pathToConvert2 , ".*\d+", '')
#$result2:          ..\myproject\afile.txt
```

Note: in the second case ref path wasn't used.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the two examples. I want one approach to solve both.

Comment: Yes I have misunderstood your example since it's pointing to file absolute path.

Comment: Not the OP, but this is what I was looking for to solve my problem. Thx