# Getting relative path from absolute path in PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, path, relative-path, absolute-path

## The problem

You have an absolute path, but you want it to be relative to another path.

Example:

```
P:/SO/data/database.txt

--> Now we want the filename to be relative to: P:/SO/team/lists/
../../data/database.txt
```

I have already found the Stack Overflow 
question *[How to convert absolute path to relative path in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396025/how-to-convert-absolute-path-to-relative-path-in-powershell)*.

One answer links to an [already developed Cmdlet](http://poshcode.org/1751), but this one didn't work for me. And the trick using `Set/Get-Location` requires the paths to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The solution

I found an answer from [Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) written in PHP: *[Getting relative path from absolute path in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2638272/603003)*.

Here is my port to PowerShell:

```
<# This is probably not the best code I've ever written, but
   I think it should be readable for most (advanced) users.

   I will wrap this function into a Cmdlet when I have time to do it.
   Feel free to edit this answer and improve it!
#>
function getRelativePath([string]$from, [string]$to, [string]$joinSlash='/') {

    $from = $from -replace "(\\)", "/";
    $to = $to -replace "(\\)", "/";

    $fromArr = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;
    $fromArr.AddRange($from.Split("/"));

    $relPath = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;
    $relPath.AddRange($to.Split("/"));


    $toArr = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;
    $toArr.AddRange($to.Split("/"));

    for ($i=0; $i -lt $fromArr.Count; $i++) {
        $dir = $fromArr[$i];

        # Find first non-matching directory
        if ($dir.Equals($toArr[$i])) {
            # ignore this directory
            $relPath.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        else {
            # Get number of remaining directories to $from
            $remaining = $fromArr.Count - $i;
            if ($remaining -gt 1) {
                # Add traversals up to first matching directory
                $padLength = ($relPath.Count + $remaining - 1);

                # Emulate array_pad() from PHP
                for (; $relPath.Count -ne ($padLength);) {
                    $relPath.Insert(0, "..");
                }
                break;
            }
            else {
                $relPath[0] = "./" + $relPath[0];
            }
        }
    }
    return $relPath -Join $joinSlash;
}
```

**Attention:**
  - You *From* path has to end with a slash!

### Example

```
getRelativePath -From "P:/SO/team/lists/" -To "P:/SO/data/database.txt";
--> ../../data/database.txt

getRelativePath -From "C:/Windows/System32/" -To "C:/Users/ComFreek/Desktop/SO.txt";
--> ../../Users/ComFreek/Desktop/SO.txt
```

Comment: Honestly I prefer this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564634/bash-convert-absolute-path-into-relative-path-given-a-current-directory?rq=1

Comment: @MikaëlMayer Your link only contains Bash solutions, and they are therefore not comparable to mine.